# Cant display a BLOB picture to BitmapButton python

Tags: python, sqlite, wxpython

**My Class**

```
class Mydb():
    def __init__ (self):
        self.conn = sqlite3.connect('C:\\lab\\pictures.db')

    def queryf(self,q):
        c = self.conn.cursor()
        c.execute(q)
        data = c.fetchone()
        return data[0]
```

**Using Mydb class**

```
....
q = "SELECT file FROM t_pictures WHERE id = 1;"
db = Mydb()
_data = db.queryf(q)
start_image = wx.Image(_data)
start_image.Rescale(150, 100)
image = wx.BitmapFromImage(start_image)
self.bitmap_button_1 = wx.BitmapButton(self, wx.ID_ANY,image)
```

**The error**

```
TypeError: String or Unicode type required
```

Comment: with open("c:\\lab\\ai.jpg", "wb") as output_file:
            q = "SELECT file FROM t_pictures WHERE id = 1;"
            db = Mydb()
            _data = db.queryf(q)
            output_file.write(_data)

Answer (score 1):

```
def Onbutton_1(self,event):
    q = "SELECT file FROM t_pictures WHERE id = 1;"
    db = Mydb()
    _buffer = db.queryf(q)
    stream = cStringIO.StringIO(_buffer)
    image = wx.ImageFromStream(stream)        
    _pic = wx.BitmapFromImage(image.Rescale(150, 100))        
    self.bitmap_button_1 = wx.BitmapButton(self, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY,_pic)
```

Answer (score 0):

The database is not returning a string from that query. You need to find out what type of object it is returning. My guess is that you are receiving a tuple. In that case, extract the string from the tuple and try putting that into your Image widget. Also make sure that you pass wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY as the second parameter to wx.Image to make the widget extra flexible. See http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.Image-class.html for more details.

Comment: When I use the same def queryf to download the picture it is working example:
        with open("c:\\lab\\ai.jpg", "wb") as output_file:
            q = "SELECT file FROM t_pictures WHERE id = 1;"
            db = Mydb()
            _data = db.queryf(q)
            output_file.write(_data)
I tried changing the 2nd parameter to wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY.

Comment: Do a **print type(_data)** and see what you get.

Comment: The result is <type 'buffer'>

Comment: That's your problem. The query is returning a buffer object, not a string.

Comment: That is why I join Stack overflow because I have a problem that needs a solution. It is more helpful for me to give me the correct and working code.